# `at` jobs running tens of minutes later than expected

Tags: linux, cron, scheduled-task, at

I have an issue with `at` jobs being queued successfully and running successfully, but sometimes tens of minutes after they are scheduled to run.

I confirmed that `atd` is running:

```
me@hostname:~$ ps -ef | grep atd
daemon    1223     1  0 Aug27 ?        00:00:00 atd
```

and that the job is scheduled

```
me@hostname:~$ atq
260 Wed Oct 28 12:02:00 2015 a me
```

and the server time is later than the scheduled time

```
me@hostname:~$ date
Wed Oct 28 12:19:57 EDT 2015
```

yet the job does not run. It does run eventually, but tens of minutes later than it is supposed to.

There are no email or log error messages from `atd`.

If I copy the contents of `at -c 260` into a script, and run it from the terminal with a blank environment, the job runs without a problem, so there doesn't seem to be any problem with the contents of the job.

This happens to some, but not all scheduled jobs. I can't identify anything different about the times when the job starts on time and the times when it is delayed.

Is this normal? Why is `at` running jobs so much later than their scheduled times? What can I do to make it run jobs at their scheduled times?

Comment: Are you sure, that it is not your job which runs for long?

Comment: @asdmin Yes; the job doesn't start at all until much later.

Comment: have you got any interesting messages in the system log?

Comment: can you share the full command line arguments of atd? I want to exclude a `-l` flag being present there.

Comment: can you try running atd in the foreground (`-f`) in debug mode (`-d`)? Perhaps it will reveal some additional details.

Comment: I see at least two options in `atd` that may influence when the job are run: -l Specifies a limiting load factor, over which batch jobs should not be run, instead of the compile-time choice of 1.5. For an SMP system with n CPUs, you will probably want to set this higher than n-1. -b Specify the minimum interval in seconds between the start of two batch jobs (60 default). How is the load of the machine?